# EC2 Instance - Start, Run Process, Stop

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an application installed on a GPU compute EC2 node that does a lot of heavy calculation. I would like to set it up to do the following:

1. Send request to GPU EC2 node to run a process.
2. If GPU EC2 node is already started, and running a process, wait until that process is finished and run the process from this new request.
3. Else Start the GPU EC2 node and run process from new request.
4. Once all processing has finished, Stop EC2 node.

I've gotten this working partially by starting/stopping instances through Lambda. I am curious, is there a more automatic, built-in, functionality in AWS to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

A better architecture might be:

- When there is work to be done, push it to an **Amazon SQS queue** (or store details in Amazon S3 and push a message that points to Amazon S3)
- Create a **CloudWatch Alarm** that triggers when the size of the queue is greater than zero
- The alarm can trigger a **Lambda function that starts the GPU node**
- The GPU instance has software running that **pulls work from the SQS queue**
- When there is no work remaining, the GPU instance calls **`shutdown`** on the operating system

Comment: +1. A similar approach is to use auto-scaling group that will scale using the same CloudWatch metric for SQS queue length instead of using Lambda.

Comment: True! I wonder how to code the scale-in? Probably have the instance reduce the _Desired Capacity_ so that Auto Scaling kills the instance, rather than using a CloudWatch Alarm that might kill an instance that is still processing.

Comment: Thank you. This was the exact type of thing I was looking for.

An edge case comes to mind, though. What if the GPU instances calls shutdown, starts shutting down, and midway through that a user sends a request for new work? Is there a way to make CloudWatch wait until the EC2 node is in a state which it can be started up again?

Comment: The Amazon CloudWatch metric would take some time to trigger (at least one minute), so there is unlikely to be a clash. However, the Lambda function might have a problem calling `StartInstances` while the instance is `Stopping`. In the Auto Scaling solution, instances are _launched_ and _terminated_, not stopped/started.

Comment: Would it be appropriate to have lambda function continually check the status of the node, waiting for when it can be started again?

What function would I use to do that? I notice that describeInstanceStatus does not actually return info on when the node is stopping. It only returns info when it is in a startup phase. How would I discern if a node is 'stopping' from lambda?

Comment: You could use a [boto3 EC32 Waiter](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#waiters). It's a bit wasteful having a Lambda function wait on an external service (eg waiting for an instance to stop), but it's easier than continually triggering a Lambda function to check for a status change.